# Unable to deploy Jenkins inside tomcat7 with Engine's non defaultHost

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, jenkins, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I am using EC2, I would like to deploy Jenkins war file inside Tomcat7 and
I would like to access only that jenkins with the EC2's IP.

Here is my excerpt of tomcat7 server.xml configuration:

```
 <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="example.com">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
       <Host name="test.example.com" appBase="hosts/hktest" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" />
       <Host name="example.com" appBase="hosts/hkprod" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Alias>www.example.com</Alias>
       </Host>

      <Host name="localhost" appBase="hosts/jenkins" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" />
    </Engine>
```

Here is the error I am getting every time I invoked "./catalina.sh run"

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid context ''. Cannot find context in host localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the context.xml file?

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context